# keyboard shortcut for inserting text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xbindkeys, xdotool

how to set a keyboard combination for inserting special string in current window at current position?

for example, when I'm on Firefox address bar, or Chrome address bar, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> it inserts `.net` at current position.

It should works globally, in any environment I am. (like in Netbeans or Eclipse, which runs by Java)

I tried to set a keyboard binding for command `xdotool type '.net'` in gnome keyboard settings, but it didn't work and typed nothing. While when I run following command in Terminal and then go to Firefox address bar, it types `.net`:

`sleep 5 && xdotool type '.net'`